# Is Ganga a wife of Vishnu according to Vishnu Purana?

Tags: vishnu, vishnu-purana, ganga

We all know that Ganga is the wife of Shantanu according to Mahabharata.
But I heard somewhere that Ganga is the wife of Vishnu.
Is it true?
Pls give proof from Vishnu Purana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganga is wife of Lord Vishnu according to Brāhma Vaivarta Purana Prakriti Khanda 6:13-21 not Vishnu Purana.

[image]